# XAML method name as string - TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, action

XAML has a nice way of allowing to use method names to set a method as a property - it uses a similar logic to assign event handlers after all, such as:

```
<!-- MyControl.xaml -->
<MyControl Event="MyControl_Event"/>
------------------------------------------
// MyControl.xaml.cs
private void MyControl_Event(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

As such, this pattern can be used to assign methods to Action and Func properties, such as:

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:SomeClass MyAction="MainWindow_Action"/>
</Window.DataContext>
-----------------------------------------------------
// SomeClass.cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public Action MyAction { get; set; }
}

// MainWindow.xaml.cs
private void MainWindow_Action() { ... }
```

This is fully functionnal in the application itself, but gives an error in visual studio (in the designer in particular): `TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String`. That error sounds like the designer fails to recognize the method name as a valid method of MainWindow, which is rather unsettling considering that, once I launch the application, everything works fine and as intended.

How can I fix this error without resorting to changing MyAction to a dependency property or an event?

Comment: I tried to reproduce but cannot.  Can you post more of your Xaml to understand the context of the `SomeClass` Xaml usage?

Comment: Adding a little more detail. I can reproduce the error in a new .NET 5.0 WPF App project using nothing other than what is shown in the question.